# .htaccess, single page app and rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hey guys so my title sounds like one you may have seen before but I promise my problem is fairly unique. I'm working within an old legacy cms that does some funky stuff with routes etc. The problem: we build a SPA that needs to live within this CMS. We're close but we're having issues with routing. to start the CMS builds out routes using the id's of the entries and appends the html. So an entry may look like /information/321.html. I want it to look like /ourapp/. Secondly, because it is a SPA, everything past the /ourapp/ route needs to path back to the route of the app for app routing purposes. Any idea how to tackle all of this?

I have the first part done with:

```
RewriteRule ^ourapp$ information/321.html [L
```

Comment: Why does a single page app care for routing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a rewriting perspective this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?ourapp/(.+)$ /information/321.html?route=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?ourapp/?$ /information/321.html [L]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration *and* in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

In case you want to use a dynamic configuration file you have to make sure that such files are considered at all by the http server (`AllowOverride` directive) and that the file is located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host and readable to the http server process.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: This solves only part of the problem though... the second part would be to point anything past ourapp route back to root of ourapp so when you navigate to a subpage of the app it will be able to handle that route

Comment: As already said in the comment to the question: no idea why that should be required for a "single page app", but anyway... I made a minor modification to the rule so that everything "under" that base path gets mapped. Though I fail to see how such an app should process such requests.